# Symfony2 and DQL: query over ManyToMany relationship

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have 2 entities: User and Archive, with a many to many relation between them:
In user entity I have:

```
/**
 * represent the script collection for a user
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="My\ApplicationBundle\Entity\Archive", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="collection")
 **/
private $collection;
```

and in Archive:

```
/**
 * represent the users having this archive in their collection
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="My\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="collection")
 **/
private $users;
```

this relationship generates a table called "collection" with an user_id and an archive_id field. Insert data in these table is not a problem.

now, I'd like to get all the archive for a specific user, but I don't know where to start. I tried

```
$this->getUser->getCollection()
```

but it seems not working as expected. Probably I'd need some custom repository class? Many thanks

Comment: When properly mapped, $user->getArchives() will work.  The collection table (really should just be users_archives) is invisible.  Doctrine 2 works on objects and not tables.  It can be a challenging concept.  Best bet is to read the manual and work some examples.  http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional

Comment: in this specific case, getArchives works but for different purposes, and getCollection works as well, but I can't understand hot to access the archive information. any suggestion for that?

Comment: ok I had a revelation :). getCollection returns an array of Archive objects, so I can call the related methods. thank you

Comment: unfortunately I need to use DQL for this, in order to paginate the results. I created a new question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788278/symfony2-and-doctrine-many-to-many-relation-using-query-builder