# Symfony2 and Doctrine: Many-to-many relation using query builder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have 2 entities: User and Archive. The user entity has, among others, two properties:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="My\ApplicationBundle\Entity\Archive", mappedBy="user")
 **/
protected $archives;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="My\ApplicationBundle\Entity\Archive", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="collection")
 **/
private $collection;
```

and the Archive entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="My\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="archives")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
protected $user;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="My\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="collection")
 **/
private $users;
```

the reason of this little mess is pretty simple: in User, $archives represent all the archives submitted by a user, $collection represent all the archives used by a user (even submitted by other users). In Archive entity, $user represent the user that submitted this archive, $users represent all the users using this archive.

So, to get the archives of one user I simply use to do:

```
$this->getUser()->getArchives();
```

and to get the collection:

```
$this->getUser()->getCollection();
```

the problem now is I have to paginate the results, so I need to use query builder. what I am doing is:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('MyApplicationBundle:Archive');

    $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->innerJoin('a.user', 'u', 'WITH', 'u = :user')
        ->where('a.active = :active')
        ->setParameters(array(
            'user' => $this->getUser(),
            'active' => 1
        ))
        ->setFirstResult($start)
        ->setMaxResults($length)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

but here the problem is I am going directly to Archive without using the collection table (there is not an entity for that). Can anyone please explain me hot to consider the collection table to filter my results?

Many thanks
Manuel

---

### SOLVED

thanks to LPodolski, this is how I changed the DQB

```
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('a')
        //->innerJoin('a.user', 'u', 'WITH', 'u = :user')
        ->innerJoin('a.users', 'cu', 'WITH', 'cu = :user')
        ->where('a.active = :active')
        ->setParameters(array(
            'user' => $this->getUser(),
            'active' => 1
        ))
        ->setFirstResult($start)
        ->setMaxResults($length)
        ->getQuery()
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>innerJoin('a.users', 'cu', 'WITH', 'cu = :collectionUser')
```

or leftJoin should do the trick

Comment: could you please be more specific? do I have to use this in place of the current innerjoin or in addiction to it? what can I pass as parameter for :collectionUser? thanks

Comment: i dont know exactly what logic do you need, if you want to filer by both then add both, if want to filter instead of current then replace

you can set :collectionUser via your setParameters method od add separate ->setParameter

Comment: oh now I see, I updated my question with the solution. thank you so much